# Call method in Parallel.Foreach and save the result into the thread safe list

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I have this code which is running fine in single thread

```
foreach (var meetingRoom in meetingRooms)
{
            try
            {
                var res = calendarService.GetEvents(meetingRoom.Email, startUtc, endUtc, lightweight, limit);
                result.AddRange(res);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Error(ex);
            }
}
```

but the issue is the meetingRooms list contains more than 40 000 entries. I am trying to approach the Parallel.Foreach - this is what I´ve got so far:

```
Parallel.ForEach(meetingRooms, () => 0,(meetingRoom) =>
        {
            var res = calendarService.GetEvents(meetingRoom.Email, startUtc, endUtc, lightweight, limit);

        }
        ,
        finalResult =>
        {
            lock (result)
            {
                result.Add(finalResult);
            }
        });
```

I do not have luck with the understanding of how the fourth parameter localFinally works.

Please note that result and meetingRooms are the lists with different datatypes.

EDIT:

I´ve implemented the PLINQ solution as one of answers indicates. Seems like its working but the Exchange Web Services(EWS) library is not implemented for parallel calling of one of its method. Getting and error "Not a unique key!" which is thrown by Microsoft code.

Comment: There isnt really a question here - I dont see a pramater of "localFinally" .. what specifically is the issue

Comment: What context is this in? ASP.NET, console, WPF, windows forms?

Comment: The samples are onconsistent in the use of `result.Add()` and `result.AddRange()`, better fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use PLinq.

```
result = meetingRooms
  .AsParallel()
  .Select(meetingRoom => calendarService.GetEvents(meetingRoom.Email, startUtc, endUtc, lightweight, limit) )
  .ToList();
```

When you still want to use Parallel.ForEach(), the overloads with localFinally aren't so useful. Use the basics:

```
Parallel.ForEach(meetingRooms, meetingRoom =>
    {
        var res = calendarService.GetEvents(meetingRoom.Email, ...);

        lock (result) // only OK when you don't lock on it anywhere else
        {
            result.Add(res);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't understand why you think that the ForEach-version with local state isn't useful. Isn't it used so that each partition can have its local state which can be accessed without locking?

Comment: Why do you think that would be useful? It can be used when your intermediate results are very small.  When GetEvents() does something substantial the localResults won't make much difference,

Comment: Given that there are 40000 meeting rooms, your version would invoke the lock statement for each iteration of the loop. A version with local state would lock only once per partition, which is considerably less. It might not matter much, if the call to GetEvents takes far more time than acquiring and releasing the lock, but that's up to the OP to discover.

Comment: An uncontested lock is a matter of nanoseconds, this has been discussed here before. Complicating your source to solve a non-existing problem is always much worse.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use a [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) (or [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ConcurrentDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx)) to store the results and avoid the lock.

Comment: *Not* a concurrent bag, that's for fast thread-*local* storage.

Comment: Depends on the needs of the application. In this case adding items is faster with a ConcurrentBag, and reading them (from the same thread, of course) will use an internal lock.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - "concurrent bag is for thread-local storage" ? Huh? That needs a citation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman docs, source code or Stephen Toub blog post? The data added by each thread is stored in TLS for faster access by its own thread. Reading other threads' data results in cross-thread operations

Comment: @HenkHolterman for example [FAQ :: Are all of the new concurrent collections lock-free?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/01/26/faq-are-all-of-the-new-concurrent-collections-lock-free/) from 2010 `it maintains a local queue for each thread that accesses it, and under some conditions, a thread is able to access its local queue in a lock-free manner with little or no contention.  Therefore, while ConcurrentBag<T> sometimes requires locking, it is a very efficient collection for certain concurrent scenarios (e.g. many threads both producing and consuming at the same rate). `

Comment: Pick one. I know what TLS is, I'm curious about what role you see for a ConcurrentBag.

Comment: How about all? FAQ was first. Stephen Toub links to [Performance of Concurrent Collections in .NET 4](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2010/04/26/performance-of-concurrent-collections-in-net-4/) second. Perhaps you should ask the PFX team intended for ConcurrentBag. I believe that article covers it

Comment: That just makes the Bag very well suited for this localResults scenario. So why did your first comment start with "Not..." ? But I just don't buy the need to avoid the lock here at all.

Comment: Why? the threads don't *consume* their own data. The consumer is the thread that ends up *reading* that data. From the perf doc : `it will not have the same behavior for pure producer-consumer scenarios as all the consumers will have to repeatedly perform stealing operations and this will incur significant overheads and synchronization costs.` Page 17. Also note the memory impact

Comment: Henk Holterman, the Concurrent collection are optimized for concurrent access, therefore usually they are faster then locks, plus you don't have to worry about handling multiple locks on the same resource.

Comment: @drevis the problem is that ConcurrentBag is a special-purpose collection. It has different performance characteristics than ConcurrentQueue, ConcurrentStack or ConcurrentDictionary. It's actually more expensive to read from it after the parallel loop finishes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos true, that's why I said that depends on the application. You can't exclude one a priori, maybe here the read is not critical.